# JS onclick function return true

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have created a button

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="enroll" onClick="return clicknow()">
```

in JS I have written `clicknow` function as follow :

```
<script>
function clicknow()
{
    jQuery('#sheduling_wait').show();
    var roll_number = jQuery('#roll_number').val();
    var class_n = jQuery('#class_n').val();
    //alert(class_n);
    var FirstData = "roll_number=" + roll_number+"&class_n="+class_n;
    var currenturl = jQuery(location).attr('href');
    var url = currenturl;
        jQuery.ajax({
            dataType : 'html',
            type: 'GET',
            url : url,
            data : FirstData,
            complete : function() { },
            success: function(data) 
                {

                    data1=jQuery(data).find('div#stfflistdiv');
                    //jQuery('#staff').show();
                    jQuery('#staff').html(data1);
                    var data2 = jQuery('#staff #stfflistdiv').html();
                    console.log(data2);
                    if(data2 == '2')
                    {
                        jQuery('#staff').show();
                        jQuery('#staff').html("This roll No is already Saved, Please add another roll no");
                        jQuery('#sheduling_wait').hide();
                        return false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        jQuery('#sheduling_wait').hide();
                        return true;
                    }

                }
        });
}
</script>
```

I have problem that when the value of `data2` is equal to 2 then the page directs instead of staying on same page due to `return false`,

How can I stay on same page if `data2 == 2` and submit when the value of `data2 == 1`

Answer (score 3):

you have to do it like this

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="enroll"> <!-- remove onclick-->
```

and then

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myform").submit(function(event){

    if(data ==2)
    {
      event.preventDefault(); //prevent the default submit action
      //...your code
    }else{
      //other code
    }

  });
});
```

Comment: it will lead to `to much recurtion` :(

Answer (score 1):

The value you return from the `success` callback is not returned by the outer function. In fact, the `success` callback is not called until the ajax call returns, which is after the outer function has already returned.

Instead of adding an `onclick` attribute to the submit button, you can register a submit-event handler on the form. Inside the submit-event handler, you can call `e.preventDefault()` to stop the normal form submission. Then when the ajax call returns and you want the form to submit, you can call the form element's `submit()` method. (Do not call `submit()` on a jQuery object that represents the form, that would cause the submit-event handler to get called again, which would result in an infinite loop. You call `submit()` on the actual form element.)

```
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#myForm').submit(function(e) { // <-- Use your form's id
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = this;
        $('#sheduling_wait').show();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: $(location).attr('href'),
            data: {
                roll_number: $('#roll_number').val(),
                class_n: $('#class_n').val()
            },
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(html) {
                var $stfflistdiv = $(html).find('#stfflistdiv');
                if ($stfflistdiv.html() == '2') {
                    $('#staff').html("This roll No is already Saved, Please add another roll no").show();
                } else {
                    $('#staff').html($stfflistdiv).show();
                    form.submit();
                }
            },
            complete: function() {
                $('#sheduling_wait').hide();
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Note:

1. Register the event handler in a document-ready handler. That is the `jQuery(function($) {` part of the code above. The `jQuery` object is passed as the first parameter, so if you name it `$`, you can then safely use `$` to represent `jQuery` inside the function even if you have called `jQuery.noConflict()`.
2. Use an object for the ajax `data` setting, rather than concatenating your own query string. It's cleaner, plus the values get properly encoded.
3. Use the `complete` callback to hide the `#sheduling_wait` element since `complete` executes even when there is an error.

Answer (score 1):

the return statement return data for succes function. not for clicknow()

options:
set variable in clicknow initial in false.
var ret=false;
and set ajax async:false (not recommended)
into success function set your variable for true or false;

if(data2 == '2') { ret=false; } else { ret=true; }

and into end function clicknow return ret;

sorry my english.

regards.